# My mouse pointer disappears on "system surfaces" , like background picture, menus, background for all kind of system menus

Tags: 11.10, mouse

I have an annoying problem with Ubuntu 11.10, my mouse pointer disappears on the Ubuntu surface ( not in programs like firefox, libre office ..)

The mouse pointer is there, but its size is only one pixel and in the white background of e.g. "system" it is not seen at all, although with "ctrl" I can see where it should be.
I have not found any place where I can change the size or colors of the mouse pointer.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Found this answer and it worked for me.

- [Mouse cursor won't appear on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66511/mouse-cursor-wont-appear-on-boot)

> I had this problem on a Dell Optiplex 955. It has something to do with
>   the video drivers and the default cursor set. You can set SWCursor on
>   in your xorg configuration as discussed in this Ubuntu Forums post,
>   however that has some performance impact (probably negligible on
>   modern systems though).
>
> What I did is edit `/usr/share/icons/default/index.theme` and changed
>   DMZ-White to whiteglass (you can change it to any of the non-DMZ
>   themes in `/usr/share/icons` with a cursor directory in its subdirectory
>   like whiteglass or redglass)
>
> After doing that, log out and back in to restart the X server.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use one of alternative cursor schemes. 
Start command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

and select the number corresponding to one of the other alternative cursor color schemes.

You should log out and log in again for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change your mouse cursor theme, to see if your current theme causes the problems.

You can use **Gnome Tweak Tool** to change the **Cursor theme** settings.

To install use Software Center or `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`. The cursor theme settings are on *Theme page -> Cursor theme*.

Alternatively **Dconf Editor** can change the size of the mouse cursor:

Install dconf-tools with Software Center or `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`.

The cursor size can be changed on: *org -> gnome -> interface -> cursor-size.*